# Why won’t border-radius make the top and bottom of this <div /> fully round?

Tags: css

This is a handle for a range slider. I want the top and bottom to be fully rounded, but no matter what I set border-radius to, the top and bottom don’t go fully round. It ends up with rounded corners and a slightly flattened top. What’s going on here?

Here’s a zoomed-in image and the actual CSS/HTML:

[image]

And the actual CSS/HTML:

```css
.handle {
 background-color: rgb(60, 158, 255);
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: rgb(60, 158, 255) 0px 0px 0px 1px;
 height: 36px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -11px;
 position: absolute;
 transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
 top: 50%;
 width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="handle"></div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I put together a demo illustrating what I’m seeing. It includes three different sizes that are scaled up 7x. This can’t be a pixel rounding thing. This zoomed-up version has about ~9px of flat before you see the curve begin.

Notice the even-numbered widths work wonderfully, and the odd number has a more flattened top and bottom. It’s definitely more round than square, but it’s undeniable that it has a somewhat flattened shape.

```css
.handles {
 align-items: center;
 bottom: 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 font-size: 7px;
 font-family: monospace, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Georgia;
 font-weight: 400;
 height: 100%;
 justify-content: center;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 transform: scale(7);
}

.label {
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 top: calc(100% + 6px);
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 width: 36px;
}

.handle {
 background-color: rgb(60, 158, 255);
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: rgb(60, 158, 255) 0px 0px 0px 1px;
 height: 36px;
 margin: 0 12px;
 position: relative;
 width: 5px;
}


.handle--even4 {
 width: 4px;
}

.handle--even6 {
 width: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="handles">
 <div class="handle handle--even4"><div class="label">4px</div></div>
 <div class="handle"><div class="label">5px</div></div>
 <div class="handle handle--even6"><div class="label">6px</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you think it's not fully round ?it looks pixalate only if you zoom in too much

Comment: You specified a width of 5 px, but your image looks bigger in your picture, just like it has a width of 15pixels

Comment: Seems round to me... Antialiasing does it fine as it seems. I suppose you're just nitpicking on something nobody will notice as much as you do. This is round. Move on to next task.

Comment: it will mostly always have 2 pixels at the top that is flat since the curve will finish on both sides and since they both finish on the same line (curve line) they will create a 2px flat. This is as good as it gets and it is good for 99.9999% of the people out there. It's good, don't get stuck on this

Comment: @Ferrybig — I mentioned above the image that it’s zoomed-in. The actual width is 5px. You have to run the code snippet to see.

Comment: It seems to me to be an odd-even numbered with thing. If I bump this down to 4px or up to 6px it rendered much better.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's fully round already. If you zoom in and check the color values of each pixel, you can see the exact same transition on the top as you see on the sides.

Your image has 2 fully-solid pixels at the very center of the top edge, which is typical. (Sometimes the center-most 1 or 2 pixels of a curve like that render fully-solid, sometimes not--quirk of rendering engines?--but they're always very close to solid.)

Maybe the contrast/gamma of your display is darkening some of the in-between anti-aliasing pixels to distort the curve you perceive? It might then appear that there are 4 fully-solid pixels on the top edge instead of 2. That would look like a flat top. Check other displays and see if you like the result better? For what it's worth, it already looks nicely rounded on my screen (when shrunk down).

(If it's a sign of anything else going on: that image is 14px wide, not the 5px stated in your CSS. Even if it's high-DPI I'd expect a 10px image, not 14. Anyway, there's no harm in setting an extra-high radius value if it helps.)

Comment: The image I included is zoomed-in quite a bit. You have to run the code snippet to see it at its actual size.

Comment: At native size from the snippet it's still round (and in fact has no solid center-pixels in my browser, desktop Safari).